# AngularJS input check/uncheck with 2 functions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a checkbox.

**Check** -> call `displayStuff();`

**Uncheck** -> call `hideStuff();`

I tried something like that but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="myCheckbox ? displayStuff() : hideStuff()" />
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this. Call a function and determine the value of 'mycheckbox'

```js
function ctrl ($scope) {
    
    function displayStuff(){
        alert("display");
    }
    
     function hideStuff() {
         alert("hide stuff");   
    }
    
    $scope.checkClick = function(){
          if($scope.mycheckbox== false)
              hideStuff();
          else
              displayStuff();
    }
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="checkClick()" />

</body>
```

However, if all you are doing is hiding/displaying things, a better approach would be to simply wrap the elements you want to hide/display with an `ng-show`

So like..

```
 <div ng-show="mycheckbox==true">
</div>
```

that way when the checkbox is clicked, it will automatically show the elements within the div, when it is unchecked, it will hide them.

Answer (score 2):

You just have a typo in *ng-model="my**C**heckbox"*.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.displayStuff = function() {
        $scope.text = 'displayStuff';
    };
    $scope.hideStuff = function() {
        $scope.text = 'hideStuff';
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="myCheckbox" data-ng-change="myCheckbox ? displayStuff() : hideStuff()" />
    <p>{{text}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kpt6XlKYoP8Jji9q7w3J?p=preview)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox2" name="mycheckbox1" ng-true-value="YES" ng-false-value="NO" ng-model="mycheckbox" ng-change="mycheckbox=='YES' ? displayStuff() : hideStuff()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a toggle function taking the model value as input.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('stuffCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = "Stuff is displayed";
  
  $scope.toggle = function(condition){
    if (condition) {
      //do stuff
      $scope.data = "Stuff is displayed";
    }
    
    else $scope.data = "Stuff is hidden";
    //do stuff
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.0" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Angular</h1>
    <div ng-controller="stuffCtrl">
    
      <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="toggle(mycheckbox)" ng-init="mycheckbox=true"> Display stuff
      <div>{{ data }}</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checked()"  ng-model="mycheckbox" />
```

> Controller:

$scope.mycheckbox = false;

```
    $scope.checked = function () {
        if ($scope.mycheckbox)
            $scope.hideStuff();
        else
            $scope.displayStuff();

    }


     $scope.displayStuff=function(){
         alert("d");
         $scope.mycheckbox=true;

    }

    $scope.hideStuff= function() {
        alert("h");
        $scope.mycheckbox=false;
    }
```